# Classification for multidimensional data

Tags: classification, svm, multidimensional-scaling

I have a dataset of timestamped measurements for various features. Each data point d is a Matrix MxN of M measurements (say time 1...M) for N different features. You can think of these as measurements over N sensors over time 1...M. Each data point (matrix) is also associated with a binary label Y which I need to predict.

Data point d matrix:

```
       sensor_1, sensor_2, ... , sensor_N
```

time_1

time_2

...

time_M

I have thought of using SVM classification, however I am not sure how should I specify a proper (and expressive) kernel in this case. Any ideas? I am considering to experiment with other algorithms as well if they can give me a better handle on the problem.